# very starnge behaviour in expect script

Tags: expect

I have expect script which I run to get some export of the live Network, but I have a stupid issue now. Script connect's to smotool, and log file to myfile.log, but today it won't work. Well when I put `exp_internal 1` or `log_user 1` it's working fine, otherwise not. It's really stupid and annoying but I don't know does anyone have idea what could I include in code. I want to hide the output, that's why I can't use `log_user 1`.
Sory if question is in some hand stupid:)

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/expect             
 match_max 1000                      
 exp_internal 0                      
 log_user 0                          
 set timeout 180                     
 spawn smotool                       
        log_file myfile.log             
        set prompt smo.*                
        expect -re $prompt              
        send -- "listnes -full"         
        expect -re $prompt
```

Comment: `log_user 0` stops the output of the spawned process from appearing in the standard output of `expect`.

Comment: yes, but with log_user 0 the script is not working, myfile.log is empty.

Comment: Correct. With `log_user 0` no output of spawned process and thereby leading empty file output since `log_file` doesn't have anything to record.